# Return Boolean from Task, That checks if string exist in Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, xamarin.forms

The Task passes through the two strings from getuser() on to DBFirebase class. It then uses those strings to check if they exist in The Firebase Realtime Database. How can i return "CheckLogin" to Loginpage?. I tried changing the task to Task, but then it prevents the string from sending to the DB. Any Suggestions?

```
//LoginPage.xaml.cs
public async void getuser()
        {
            await services.LoginCheck(EmailEntry.Text, PasswordEntry.Text);
                       
        }
```

```
//DBFirebase.cs
public async Task LoginCheck(string email, string password)
        {

            var LoginCheck = (await Client.Child("users").OnceAsync<users>()).FirstOrDefault(a => a.Object.email == email && a.Object.password == password);
            if (LoginCheck == null)
            {
                CheckLogin = false;

            }
            else
            {
                CheckLogin = true;
            }
```

Comment: This should read "I tried changing the task to Task<bool>" but doesn't allow me to include the bool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public async Task<bool> LoginCheck(string email, string password)
    {
        bool CheckLogin = false;

        var LoginCheck = (await Client.Child("users").OnceAsync<users>()).FirstOrDefault(a => a.Object.email == email && a.Object.password == password);
        if (LoginCheck == null)
        {
            CheckLogin = false;

        }
        else
        {
            CheckLogin = true;
        }

        return CheckLogin;
    }
```

to call it

```
var check = await services.LoginCheck(EmailEntry.Text, PasswordEntry.Text);
```

Comment: see my last edit.  This is pretty basic C#

Comment: Works Perfectly, Life saver.